# Как назвать такое сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые

> В процессе затяжного судебного разбирательства он смог закалить характер и стать настойчивым и упорным человеком.

Считаю, что сказуемое: *смог закалить и стать настойчивым и упорным человеком*.

Но как оно называется? Составное глагольное, включающее в себя составное именное?

Чем осложнено такое предложение? Просто однородными сказуемыми?

Answer (score 3):

*В процессе затяжного судебного разбирательства он **смог закалить** характер **и стать** настойчивым и упорным **человеком.***

1. Сказуемое: ***смог закалить и (смог) стать человеком.*** Это однородные сказуемые, связанные союзом И. Предложение осложнено однородными сказуемыми и однородными определениями «настойчивым и упорным».
2. Сказуемое (1)  – ***смог закалить***, составное глагольное, модальный глагол «смог»  в качестве связки + основной глагол «закалить».

Сказумое (2)  – **(смог) стать человеком**, осложненное сказуемое,  в нем две связки: модальный глагол «смог» и полузнаменательная связка «стать» со значением становления признака + именная часть «человеком» (сущ. в форме Т.п.).

3. Из словаря:

**ЧЕЛОВЕК,**  2. **Личность** как воплощение высоких моральных и интеллектуальных свойств. **Быть настоящим человеком.** Воспитать человека. Ч. с большой буквы. Стать человеком; из кого-л. вышел ч. (о том, кто достиг определённого положения, уважения, авторитета).

**ЗАКАЛИТЬ,** 3. кого (что), (в чём, чем). Сделать выносливым, способным к преодолению трудностей, лишений, неблагоприятных условий. Трудности закалили нас. **З. волю, характер, душу.**

**СТАТЬ**, св. 7. (нсв. становиться). Употр. как вспомогательный глагол в составном именном сказуемом со зн.: сделать кем-, чем-л., каким-л., прийти в какое-л. состояние. **С. агрономом. С. учёным, бизнесменом, менеджером, фермером.**

Из словаря  мы видим, что  «человек» и «закалить» имеют **определенное значение**, поэтому отнесенные к ним слова являются **распространителями** и в состав сказуемого **не входят.**

Answer (score 2):

Расширенный комментарий к ответу **Sharon** в этой теме.

Из ответа **Sharon**:

> 1. Сказуемое: **смог закалить и (смог) стать человеком.**

Думаю, неправильно исключать из состава сказуемого слова **"настойчивым и упорным"**. Слово "человек" в подобных рассматриваемому предложениях, как писал когда-то Розенталь, не выступает само по себе в роли сказуемого, так как не выражает признака, приписываемого подлежащему, и без определяющих его слов не имеет нужного для данного случая смысла. Смысл ведь заключается не в том, что "он" смог стать человеком (человеком "он" был и до судебного разбирательства), а в том, что "он" смог стать **настойчивым и упорным**. И рассматриваемое предложение сохранит этот смысл, даже если слово "человек" вообще убрать из него:

***В процессе затяжного судебного разбирательства он смог закалить характер и стать настойчивым и упорным.***

Comment: У слова «человек» есть прямое значение, то есть это определенный биологический вид, «живое существо, обладающее мышлением, речью, способностью создавать орудия и т.д.». Но его второе значение (личность как воплощение высоких моральных и интеллектуальных свойств) также имеет место, оно употребляется вполне самостоятельно даже в нашей обыденной речи (например, «будь человеком»). А все определения, которых может быть множество, дополняют наше представления о качествах человека как личности. Я считаю, что это именно распространители, в грамматическую основу предложения они не входят.

Comment: _Sharon: А все определения, которых может быть множество, дополняют наше представления о качествах человека как личности. Я считаю, что это именно распространители, в грамматическую основу предложения они не входят._  === Ну а какое сказуемое Вы видите тогда в таком, к примеру, предложении: _**"Он — хороший человек"**_?  Напомню, что Кустова, на которую Вы часто ссылаетесь, сказуемым здесь считает всё сочетание "хороший человек".

Comment: Если Кустова так считает, то можете ей доверять. Но, вероятно,  задача решается с учетом специфики каждого случая. У вас субъективная  и весьма неопределенная оценка, там набор моральных качеств. Поиск единого решения на все случаи жизни не всегда бывает успешным.

Comment: Sharon, ну что Вы упорствуете? Вы же давно уже поняли, что были неправы! Ну а если не поняли...

Comment: Оставьте свои выводы при себе, пожалуйста. Вы опять начинаете считать, что все заблуждаются, кроме вас. Вы даже знаете, что я поняла, а что не поняла. Может быть, вы "сверхразум", с особыми пространствами общаетесь, мысли умеете читать, но я в этом не уверена. Давайте остановимся на такой точке зрения: больше мнений, хороших и разных. Окружающие, а также автор вопроса выберут то, что им подойдет. Я всегда могу изменить свою точку зрения, если посчитаю это нужным, но вы меня пока не убедили. Слово "человек" можно распространить определительным оборотом/придаточным, с ними-то что будете делать?

Comment: _Sharon: Слово "человек" можно распространить определительным оборотом/придаточным, с ними-то что будете делать?_ === Если повнимательнее почитаете хотя бы учебник Кустовой, что у Вас есть, ответ сумеете найти сами. (Очень хочется на это надеяться.)