# Как определить именную часть сказуемого со словом «человек»?

Tags: грамматика, сказуемые

Есть предположение, что  «человек» – это слово **лексически ослабленное и информативно недостаточное**. Поэтому оно в предложениях образует с другими словами (обычно определениями) синтаксически **несвободные** (цельные, неделимые) **словосочетания**, выступающие **в роли единого члена предложения.**

Как в таком случае определить состав именной части сказуемого, если в него входит  слово «человек» и **распространенные определения различного вида**, например: ряд однородных определений, обособленные  обороты, придаточные определительные предложения и т.д.

Примеры:

(1) Это был  коренастый человек в коричневом френче, в галифе, в огромной папахе.

(2) Он человек, который любую чепуху раздует в событие вселенского масштаба.

(3) Он человек, всегда имеющий свое собственное мнение.

Спасибо.

**Дополнение**

Я просматривала **список синтаксически несвободных сочетаний.** Мне он показался очень неоднородным, как-то не просматривается принципиальная идея, в соответствии с которой он составлен. В частности, меня удивляют эти "лексически ослабленные и информативно недостаточные" слова.

Вот, к примеру, **переходные глаголы**, требующие обязательного дополнения, тоже в какой-то мере информативно недостаточны, но мы же не считаем это сочетание единым членом предложения.

В такой же ситуации находится слово "человек". Если можно так выразиться, у него **открытая (обязательная) валентность на определение** (как у свободных радикалов, которыми нас любят пугать).

Этим словам безразлично, какая конструкция займет позицию определения (слово, однородный ряд, обособленное определение или придаточное предложение). Эта связь **должна быть закрыта,** вот тогда и получится **информативно достаточное сочетание.**

Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение по этому вопросу.

Похожая тема обсуждалась на форуме: "[Как назвать такое сказуемое](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463655/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5)".

**Из комментария (пожелание для меня):**  Если повнимательнее почитаете хотя бы учебник Кустовой, что у Вас есть, ответ сумеете найти сами. (Очень хочется на это надеяться.)

Я прочитала "хотя бы Кустову" тоже, у нее такой пример: *Он хороший человек*. Но, возможно, у этого сочетания единая семантика, а не синтаксис. "Хороший человек" имеет вполне конкретное содержание именно как сочетание.

Comment: Есть еще такая конструкция: "Человек это был коренастый", синонимичная первой. А цельные словосочетания не допускают разрыв слов.

Comment: Почему не допускают? Например: десять лет - десять долгих лет. Мы с подругой - мы с моей подругой.

Comment: потому что "десять долгих лет" это цельное сочетание. Оно не разделяется словом. Аналогично и "мы с моей подругой"

Comment: Спасибо, еще сюрприз. Значит, и в эти сочетание можно поместить длинный ряд однородных определений?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, вроде как "мы с моей подругой" - это словосочетание + определение. Но тогда встает вопрос, а как может определение относиться не ко всему цельному сочетанию? Ведь нельзя же сказать "моей мы с подругой". Как быть? Пусть знатоки синтаксиса разрешат это противоречие.

Comment: Ну да, хорошо бы они решили, да вот не хотят пока. А у меня к этому вопросу, между прочим,  личный интерес

Comment: Я думаю, что слово "человек" похоже на слово "быть". Может быть использовано в полном значении или как связка, вспомогательный элемент. Морской дьявол оказался человеком. Я человек простой. Во втором случае акцент на том, что автор простой, а не сложный, а не на том, что он человек.

Comment: Смысловой  аспект понятен, но вас ведь грамматика интересовала. Вы же не будете выдвигать новую теорию  о том, что  слово с неопределенным значением можно считать связкой.  Боюсь, что лингвисты такого новшества не оценят. Можно задуматься о СЕМАНТИЧЕСКОМ  единстве подобных сочетаний, в которых основной смысл передается простым определением. Но когда вы используете сложные и распространенные конструкции,  то это уже  ближе к ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЮ для слова человек со значением "личность", а не биологический вид (в словаре есть такое значение).

Comment: Думаю, словосочетание "коренастый человек" выражает достаточный смысл,
поэтому относить однородный ряд к сказуемым не совсем верно.

Comment: Серж, я у Кустовой вроде бы нашла это решение с распространенным определением и устойчивыми сочетаниями. На стр.9 она рассматривает простые и сложные словосочетания, в том числе соднородными отношениями. И вот там каждый член ряда отдельно относится к слову с неопределенным значением. Посмотрите, интересно https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Да, я читал эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

"Десять лет" и "мы с подругой" не являются цельными словосочетаниями.
Как может определение относиться не ко всему цельному сочетанию? Спокойно: можете говорить "моей мы с подругой", "впереди телеги лошадь" и т. д., просто не все Вас понимать будут, а так никакого противоречия нет. А если и есть, то надуманное.

Comment: Местоимения Вы, Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров: 
а) личное письмо (адресат – одно лицо); 
б) официальные документы, адресованные одному лицу; 
в) анкеты, рекламные листовки (текст, адресованный неконкретному лицу).