# Зачем нужно «это» в предложениях одновременно с тире? Что значит «это» в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, семантика

Часто можно видеть предложения типа:

«Физика — это раздел естествознания, наука о материи, её структуре и движении, простейших и общих законах природы» ([источник](https://znaki.fm/physics/) текста для примера).

Иногда можно встретить подобные определения без «это»:

«Фи́зик — учёный, чьи научные исследования в основном посвящены физике» (источник текста для примера [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA)).

**Зачем тут тире?**

Читаем в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5):

> Тире, прежде всего, означает пропуски — пропуск связки в сказуемом,
> пропуск члена предложения в неполных предложениях и в предложениях с
> нулевым сказуемым, пропуск противительных союзов. Тире как бы
> компенсирует эти пропущенные слова, сохраняет принадлежащее им место,
> например...:
>
> «Солотча — извилистая, неглубокая река» (К. Паустовский); — пропуск
> связки...

Таким образом, тире в данном случае заменяет пропущенную связку.
Если связку восстановить будет так:

«Физика **есть** это раздел естествознания, наука о материи, её структуре и движении, простейших и общих законах природы».

«Фи́зик **есть** учёный, чьи научные исследования в основном посвящены физике».

Если «Фи́зик есть учёный...» выглядит нормально, то «Физика есть это раздел...» — выглядит странно!

**Теперь вопрос: зачем тут «это»?**

Ищем в Словаре русского языка в 4 томах РАН Евгеньевой определение слова «это». Единственное, что подходит:

> э́то, нескл., ср. В качестве связки в составном сказуемом. *— Быть
> молодым и не уметь — это сносно; но состариться и не быть в силах —
> это тяжело.* Тургенев, Дворянское гнездо.

Ага! «Это» тоже, как и тире, используется в качестве связки в составном сказуемом. Так у нас в предложении две связки?!

«Физика — это раздел естествознания, наука о материи, её структуре и движении, простейших и общих законах природы».

превращается в:

«Физика **есть есть** раздел естествознания, наука о материи, её структуре и движении, простейших и общих законах природы».

Но это всё равно, что поставить два знака равно: 2 + 2 = = 4.

Зачем? Чтоб точно убедиться, что таки равно?

Для чего в качестве связки использовать «это», если пропущенную связку уже заменяет тире?

Разъясните, пожалуйста:

1. Зачем нужно «это» в данном случае, какова его функция?
2. Каково определение слова «это» по словарю в этом контексте, если я, возможно, неправильно выбрал определение из списка?
3. Почему в одних случаях «это» используется, а в других — нет? Какое грамматическое правило это регулирует.

P. S. Ещё предложения для примеров:

- Поэзия — это огненный взор юноши, кипящего избытком сил (Белинский).
  Тут есть «это».
- Геометрия — отдел математики, изучающий пространственные формы и
  отношения тел (пример из справочника Розенталя). Тут нет «это».

Answer (score 1):

```
Зачем тут это?
```

Указательное местоимение **это** может быть либо подлежащим, либо указательной частицей (либо чем-то еще).

Обычно **это** служит указателем на сказуемое (указательная частица, не являющаяся членом предложения).

```
Голод - это беда.
Есть помидоры - это приятно.
Лада - это была машина.
Баня - это хорошо.
Служба - это другое дело.
```

Но если мы изменим порядок слов, поменяются ли сказуемое с подлежащим? Будет ли **это** реализовывать декларируемую указательную функцию?

```
Беда ― это был голод. 
Приятно - это было есть помидоры. 
Машина - это была лада. (Пелевин)
Хорошо - это баня.
Другое дело - это служба.
```

А если мы используем **это** в качестве подлежащего, тогда почему согласование в роде идет с именной частью, а не с подлежащим?

```
Это была толпа. // Подлежащее - это
Это был мой брат. // Подлежащее - это
Человек это был коренастый. // Подлежащее - это
```

Так уж в синтаксисе повелось, что подлежащее **это** выбивается из ряда остальных подлежащих по согласованию. Но реальному языку не интересны проблемы синтаксиса.

```
Зачем тут тире?
```

Если кратко - незачем, но так принято. Т.е. затем, чтобы следовать правилам, которые написаны затем, чтобы им следовали. А теперь немного подробнее.
Тире означает не только пропуск глагола (языковая функция). Оно имеет какие-то пунктуационные функции (не языковые, и не синтаксические (пунктуация отражает синтаксичекскую структуру, но, как правило, не определяет её, а просто дублирует. Поэтому  редко несет синтаксическую функцию)).
Например: показать паузу, содействовать удобству чтения, расставить акценты на словах, продублировать синтаксическую структуру. Из этого списка самая бессмысленная функция - это дублирование синтаксической структуры. Это наш случай. Есть какие-то правила-соглашения и им просто надо следовать, или нет.

PS Есть еще конструкции типа

```
Всё шумело. Это ветки бились друг о друга.
```

Тут по науке какая-то совсем сложная функция у **это**. Вроде как макроподлежащее называется. Пример из какой-то статьи или учебника.

ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ
Попробуем объединить разнородные конструкции с это-указателем на сказуемое, это-подлежащим и это-макроподлежащим в одну единственную конструкцию:

```
1. Все шумело. Это ветки бились друг об друга.
2. Это - это хорошо.
3. Другое дело - это была служба.
4. Служба - это было другое дело.
5. Человек это был коренастый.
```

Преобразуем в такое:

```
1. Все шумело - ветки бились друг об друга.
2. Это! Это хорошо.
3. Другое дело - была служба.
4. Служба! Это было другое дело.
5. Человек (это) был коренастый.
```

Синтаксически интерпретируем как макроконструкцию вида **A - это Б** и обзываем А и Б макросказуемым и макроподлежащим, вместо которых подставляем конкретные грамматические основы:

```
1. (Все шумело) - это (ветки бились друг об друга). // Макроподлежащее: "Все шумело"
2. (Это) - это (хорошо). // Макроподлежащее: "Это"
3. (Другое дело) - это (была служба).  // Макроподлежащее: "Другое дело" Макросказуемое: "была служба"
```

Чтож 3 и 5 конструкций мы подвели под общий знаменатель в виде конструкции: **Макросказуемое - это макроподлежащее**. Тире в этих конструкциях несет роль пропущенного глагола **есть** в макропредложении! (Физика) -есть- (это наука). Глагол **есть** нельзя прямо подставить в макропредложение, не нарушив его корректности. Вместо этого надо подставлять косвенно:

```
А есть Б. Где А - это физика, а Б - это наука.
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако не всё понятно. Вы пишете: «Указательное местоимение это может быть либо подлежащим, либо указательной частицей (либо чем-то ещё)». Подлежащее является членом предложения, а местоимение и частица — частями речи. Исходя из того, что написано: одна часть речи (местоимение) может быть другой частью речи (частицей). Грамматические категории, как и категории вообще, взаимоисключают друг друга. Перед нами или животное (напр., собака), или здание (напр., жилой дом). Мы не можем отнести собаку в каких-то случаях к зданиям. Категории задают разбиение на непересекающиеся классы.

Comment: Вы пишете «Обычно это служит указателем на сказуемое», однако если «это», как вы сказали, указательное местоимение, то оно должно указывать на то, какой объект имеет в виду говорящий или на расположение объекта относительно говорящего (или адресата), а не на сказуемое. Например, родитель может показать рукой на трамвай своему маленькому ребёнку и сказать: «Смотри, это трамвай».
Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник утверждения «Обычно "это" служит указателем на сказуемое». (часть 1/3)

Comment: Если «это» в данном случае, указательная частица, то она должна служить для связывания и указательного подчёркивания слов, а не указывать на сказуемое в предложении. (2/3)

Comment: Согласно словарю РАН Евгеньевой «это» в значении указательной частицы: «Употребляется для подчёркивания какого-либо члена предложения. [Аполлинария:] Ведь это мужчины только непостоянны, а женская любовь и верность — до гроба. А. Островский, Красавец-мужчина. — Самойлов, это вас я застал с папироской в аудитории? — ехидно спросил Лев Никанорыч. — Меня! — с охотой признался Женька. Гранин, Искатели. || Разг. Указывает на мысль или отдельное слово, выраженные в предшествующем повествовании. [Серебряков:] С этим юродивым я и разговаривать не стану. [Соня:] Это как угодно. Чехов, Дядя Ваня». (3/3)

Comment: Как вы пришли к выводу, что «это» в данном контексте именно указательная частица? Согласно словарю «это» в качестве указательной частицы употребляется для подчёркивания какого-либо члена предложения. *«Ведь это мужчины только непостоянны …»* — подчёркивается «мужчины». *«...это вас я застал с папироской...»* — подчёркивается «вас». Не кого-то другого, а именно «вас»! Что подчёркивается в *«Физика — это раздел естествознания...»*? «Физика?» — сомнительно.

Comment: Вы пишите: *«Но если мы изменим порядок слов, поменяются ли сказуемое с подлежащим?»* Изменение порядка слов — изменение следования челнов предложения: подлежащего, сказуемого, дополнения и т. д. А не изменение сказуемого на подлежащее. Предложение является законченной мыслью. Если изменить подлежащее, то это уже другая мысль, и соответственно другое переложение, это уже не просто изменение порядка слов. (1/2)

Comment: *«Голод — это беда»*. Подлежащее «голод», и мы утверждаем, что он является бедой, что верно. Это одна мысль. *«Беда — это голод»*. Подлежащее «беда», и мы утверждаем, что она является голодом, что ложно, потому что не всякая беда является голодом. Это уже совсем другая, ложная мысль, а не изменение порядка слов. При изменении порядка слов мысль не меняется. А у вас ещё и время стало прошедшим: *«Беда ― это был голод»*. Это уже другое предложение, а не другой порядок слов в том же предложении. *«Кошка ест сосиски». «Сосиски ест кошка».* Та же мысль, но другой порядок слов.

Comment: *«Это была толпа. // Подлежащее — это. Это был мой брат. // Подлежащее — это».* Тут «это» употребляется в значении указательного местоимения, и указывает на объект/лицо уже упомянутое. Хотя вы интересно подметили, что тут нет согласования с подлежащим, я спрашивал не про данный контекст употребления слова «это». В данном случае по словарю РАН Евгеньевой «э́то, нескл., ср. В функции несогласованного подлежащего». (1/3)

Comment: Почему подлежащее несогласованное, я не знаю, но могу предположить, что «это» тут «универсальный солдат», как английское «it». И используется, для замены имён любых объектов. Поскольку «это» заменяет, то, что впоследствии названо толпой и братом, то и глагол согласуется по роду с тем, что было заменено словом «это»: толпой и братом. Т. е. под «это» как бы «прячется» та самая толпа и брат, и согласование происходит с тем, что «прячется» под подлежащим, а не с самим словом «это», которое как бы вообще не имеет признаков рода, а заменят всё что угодно. (2/3)

Comment: *«Человек это был коренастый. // Подлежащее — это».* Подлежащее тут «человек», а «это» тут не является вообще членом предложения, потому что оно — усилительная частица. По словарю РАН Евгеньевой: «2. усилительная … Разг. Логически выделяет, подчеркивает какое-л. слово, употребляясь после него. *— Иду это по улице, как шарахнется мимо рысак… Чуть-чуть не задавил.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Хлеб». «Это» здесь стоит после слова «человек» и логически выделяет, подчёркивает его. (3/3)

Comment: *«Так уж в синтаксисе повелось, что подлежащее это выбивается из ряда остальных подлежащих по согласованию. Но реальному языку не интересны проблемы синтаксиса».* Как вы пришли к выводу, что в *«Физика — это раздел естествознания...»* слово «это» — подлежащее? На мой взгляд, подлежащее тут «Физика». Поясните. В случае «Это была толпа». «Это» — действительно подлежащее. Но в *«Физика — это раздел естествознания...»* речь идёт не об «это», а о «физике».

Comment: *«Всё шумело. Это ветки бились друг о друга».* Интересный пример. Тут грамматически описать действительно трудно. Однако понятно, что «это» — указательное местоимение, которое указывает на то, о чём говорилось в предыдущем повествовании. Смысл такой: «Всё шумело. Это *были* ветки, *которые* бились друг об друга». Для чего здесь «это» понятно. Тут не наш случай.

Comment: *«Зачем тут тире? Если кратко - незачем, но так принято».* Скорее всего так оно и есть, потому что в качестве связки должно использоваться или тире, или «это», а не всё сразу. Однако, если что-то стало принято, когда-то этому была причина. Или тут имеет место массовая ошибка людей в написании тире вместе с «это».

Comment: *«Из этого списка самая бессмысленная функция - это дублирование синтаксической структуры. Это наш случай».* Я вот это не понял. Что значит «дублирование синтаксической структуры». На мой взгляд, основная функция пунктуации, это передавать в письменной речи то, что нельзя передать посредством букв. В устной речи, помимо слов, мы используем интонацию (например, для вопроса или восклицания), паузы (например, для разделения смысловых частей речи) и т. п. В письменной речи мы не можем пользоваться «звуковыми эффектами», поэтому используется пунктуация. (1/3)

Comment: Тире действительно может заменять паузу в устной речи. Может и в данном случае так. Например: *«Геометрия (пауза) отдел математики, изучающий пространственные формы ...»*. Учителя действительно делают паузу, когда диктуют определения, эта пауза показывает пропущенную связку, и что дальше пойдёт сказуемое (толкование того, что было названо). (2/3)

Comment: Может, в конструкции «— это» слово «это» выполняет функцию связки, а тире ставится для того, чтоб при чтении сделали паузу? *«Физика (пауза) это раздел естествознания...»*. **Но остаётся вопрос: зачем вообще использовать «это»?** В чём разница между «Геометрия — отдел математики...» и «Физика — это раздел естествознания...». Приведены реально существующие примеры. Почему в одних случаях есть «это», в других — нет. Зачем оно вообще там нужно? **Мой вопрос больше про «это», а не про тире.** (3/3)

Comment: Выберу самые острые вопросы для пояснения, остальное вы уж сами как-нибудь. "Подлежащее тут «человек»" - ошибаетесь. В соответствии с текущим взглядом подлежащее "это". См учебник  "сборник упражнений по синтаксису современного русского языка (с элементами программирования) 1973" стр 18. Оттуда пример (ответы в конце). Также обратите внимание на https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463807

Comment: «Физика — это раздел естествознания...» слово «это» — подлежащее? 
-- я нигде этого не писал. В данном случае это указательная частица, что следует из моего ответа. "Как вы пришли к выводу, что «это» в данном контексте именно указательная частица?" Посмотрел в справочник (6-й пункт) https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/tire_podl_skaz.html

Comment: "Изменение порядка слов — изменение следования челнов предложения: подлежащего, сказуемого, дополнения и т. д. А не изменение сказуемого на подлежащее. " Ничего подобного. В русском языке есть множество примеров, где порядок слов меняет сказуемое. Например: http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_15_303
если инфинитив стоит на первом месте в предложении, а дальше следует слово на –О, перед нами двусоставное предложение с подлежащим - инфинитивом:  Перестановка инфинитива на второе место после слова на –О, являющегося категорией состояния, превращает предложение в безличное:

Comment: В нашем же случае всё ещё проще. "Машина - это была лада" и "Лада - это была машина" меняют не только порядок слов, но и контексты. В первом предожении под машиной понимается какая-то конкретная машина (подлежащее), которая приравнивается к классу машин (Лада) - сказуемых. Во втором случае наоборот. Поясняется название марки, классом - машины

Comment: "На мой взгляд, основная функция пунктуации, это передавать в письменной речи то, что нельзя передать посредством букв.". В каких-то предложениях это действительно так. Например: "Казнить, нельзя помиловать.". Здесь от постановки запятой зависит смысл предложения. Но в большинстве предложений запятые ставятся ОДНОЗНАЧНО. А раз они там ставятся однозначно, то зачем они вообще нужны? "светлый, летний день" - запятая ставится однозначно и тупо дублирует/подчеркивает синтаксическую структуру - однородные определения. Которая и так очевидна и однозначна. Но лучше продублировать "для дураков"

Comment: *"См учебник "сборник упражнений по синтаксису современного русского языка (с элементами программирования) 1973" стр 18."* Я не вижу на стр. 18 такого предложения это сборник упражнений, а не учебник.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском в pdf по слову человек. Там не так много вхождений. Мне еще работе с pdf файлами вас учить и тыкать носом в предложения? Сборник упражнений с ответами  можно назвать учебником в общем смысле. Будем заниматься буквоедством или говорить о сути?

Comment: *«...подлежащее? -- я нигде этого не писал...»* — вы действительно такого не писали, однако вы вели речь об «это», как о подлежащем, отвечая на мой вопрос, и я подумал, что вы имеете в виду, что в моём случае оно подлежащее.

Тут izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/tire_podl_skaz.html на самом деле написано, что «это» в таких случаях указательная частица, но я с этим не согласен. На что она указывает? Источник не авторитетный, даже автора нет.

Comment: Ну и, первый ваш вопрос про частицу-местоимение. Тут вы меня подловили. Местоимения не могут быть одновременно служебными частями речи. Но сам класс служебных (несамостоятельных) частей речи во-многом определяется  синтаксисом конкретного предложения. В то время как самостоятельные части речи практически не зависят от синтаксиса конкретного предложения. Короче, я бы назвал служебные части речи - служебными членами предложения, а не служебными частями речи. И тогда уже можно говорить, что указательное местоимение играет роль указательной частицы. Но не будем спорить с терминологией, вы правы.

Comment: Я попробую добавить в свой ответ, теорию объединяющую "это"-указатель на сказуемое с "это"-подлежащим. Это будет единый взгляд на это, новая теория.

Comment: "Авторитетных источников" вы не найдете. Русский язык не математика. Ко всем источникам можно предъявить обоснованные претензии. Беда в том, что даже неавторитетных источников не найти по большинству вопросов. Приходится сочинять самому на ходу.

Comment: *«"Машина - это была лада" и "Лада - это была машина" меняют не только порядок слов, но и контексты».*

Контекст немножко из другой оперы. Контекст — это законченный в смысловом отношении отрезок письменной речи, позволяющий установить значение входящего в него слова или фразы (словарь РАН Евгеньевой). (1/3)

Comment: О контексте можно вести речь при выборе значения слова, когда слово многозначно. Например, есть «день» — часть суток от восхода до захода солнца. *Продолжим работу завтра днём.* Это один контекст. И «день» — отрезок времени в 24 часа. *Прошло пять дней после нашей встречи.* Это другой контекст использования слова день. (2/3)

Comment: *«"Машина - это была лада" и "Лада - это была машина"* — сходный контекст использования слова «это». Оно тут используется в том же значении.
А мысль эти предложения выражают разную, поэтому я не склонен считать это простым изменением порядка слов. Кроме того «была» получается ещё одна связка. Связку уже заменяет тире или «это» и причём связку настоящего времени. А тут получилось два времени в предложении. (3/3).

Comment: Да значения у слова "машина" разные в этих предложениях. Так что можно не считать это изменением порядка слов, хотя формально это просто изменение порядка слов. Вот кстати ссылка на источник https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Но вообще, в РЯ существуют примеры чистого изменения порядка слов, приводящего к изменению сказуемого. Я его приводил со ссылкой выше. Думаю, что и для конструкции "А - это Б"/"Б- это А" такие примеры возможны. Лень искать.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры. Посмотрел.

*Машина ― это была "лада" кооперативного пошиба с яркими на клейками на заднем стекле ― опять набирала скорость; видимо, водитель испугался, хотя виноват он не был.* [Виктор Пелевин. Ника (1992)]

Тут другое правило:


[§ 174. Посредством тире выделяются:](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire)

1. Предложения и слова, вставляемые в середину предложения с целью пояснения или дополнения его, в тех случаях, когда выделение скобками (см. § 188) может ослабить связь между вставкой и основным предложением… (1/4)

Comment: 2. Распространённое приложение, стоящее после определяемого cyществительного, если необходимо подчеркнуть оттенок самостоятельности такого приложения (о запятых при приложении см. § 152), например:

*Старший урядник – бравый престарелый казак с нашивками за сверхсрочную службу – скомандовал «строиться».* Шолохов

*Перед дверями клуба – широкого бревенчатого дома – гостей ожидали рабочие со знамёнами.* Федин (2/4)

Comment: *«это была "лада" кооперативного пошиба с яркими наклейками на заднем стекле»* выделено тире с двух сторон, в данном случае это предложение вставленное в середину другого предложения *«Машина … опять набирала скорость...»* с целью пояснения. «Это» тут указательное местоимение, а тире с двух сторон просто выполняют функцию скобок или запятых, отделяя внутренне предложение с пояснением. (3/4)

Comment: Во втором предложении:
*Дяде Валере только в гараже мужики объяснили, что машина это была не простая, а гэбэшная, с роторным двигателем, их ограниченной партией выпускают.* [А. А. Новиков, Г. Д. Митин, С. Л. Львов. Красная книга // «Автопилот», 2002.05.15]

Тире тут нет вовсе, а «это» — усилительная частица, которая стоит после слова машина и выделяет, подчёркивает его. (4/4)

Comment: Во втором предложении "это" - подлежащее. аналогично как в "человек это был коренастый" cм https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46380. В первом предложении я не заметил второго тире, так что пример не годится. Тем не менее предложение "Машина ― это была "лада" кооперативного пошиба с яркими наклейками на заднем стекле" очевидно корректно, просто под машиной здесь понимается не машина вообще, а конкретная машина. То есть нельзя сравнивать с "Лада - это машина".

Comment: Вот пример, как порядок слов меняет сказуемое:
Москва – столица России; Столица России – Москва.

Comment: *«Вот пример, как порядок слов меняет сказуемое: Москва – столица России; Столица России – Москва».* Хороший пример. Тут действительно смысл не меняется особо. Так происходит потому, что понятия «Москва» и «столица России» полностью тождественны. Возможно только меняется логическое ударение. В первом случае ударение на том, что именно Москва столица России, а не Германии, например. А во втором, что Столица России именно Москва, а не Лондон, например.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Какие бывают связки?**

Их два вида – **глагольная связка** БЫТЬ  в нужной форме при именном сказуемом  и специальные **слова-связки,** в том числе связка ЭТО.  Надо иметь в виду, что это совершенно разные связки с различными функциями, они не могут заменять друг друга.

При пропуске глагольной связки  ЕСТЬ  в настоящем времени может ставиться тире, но оно ставится не всегда.  Например: *Солотча –  неглубокая река. Солотча – это неглубокая река. Солотча неглубокая.*

2. **Особая грамматика**
   Предложения со связкой ЭТО имеют особую грамматику, это один из частных видов предложений **с именительным темы.** Задается именительный темы (подлежащее Солотча), ставится тире, затем местоимение ЭТО заменяет именительный темы (фактически оно повторяет подлежащее), а далее следует именная часть сказуемого (река).
3. **В каких случаях используется связка**

Почему мы  иногда  используем связку ЭТО, а иногда  обходимся без нее? Нет тут никаких правил, всё от  текста зависит, от его структуры. Некоторые  предложения со связкой читаются лучше, а иногда она не нужна.

4. **Об инверсии**

Здесь важно видеть два типа предложений – (1) взаимозаменяемые тождества и  (2) предмет и его характеристика.

(1) **Тождества**: *Москва – столица России. Столица России –  Москва*. В тождествах  подлежащее и сказуемое можно переставить местами, при этом ничего не изменится, тире ставится в обоих случаях, инверсии нет.

(2) **Предмет и его характеристика**: *Мои соседи – славные люди. Славные люди соседи мои.* Здесь подлежащее (соседи)обозначает предмет, а сказуемое (славные люди) его характеризует. При перестановке мы имеем инверсию, по основному правилу тире не ставится.

5. **Инверсия при наличии связки ЭТО**

(1) *Находить приметы – это интересное занятие*. Предложение со связкой  ЭТО, подлежащее выражено инфинитивом.

(2) *Это интересное занятие – находить приметы*.  Здесь указательное местоимение ЭТО в роли подлежащего, занятие – сказуемое, находить приметы – обособленное приложение, выраженное инфинитивом и раскрывающее  содержание местоимения.

Мы видим, что тире ставится в обоих случаях, но грамматика разная.

Comment: Я не пойму, в «Солотча неглубокая.» вы неумышленно упустили слово река, или в случае отсутствия тире и «это», слова «река» тут не должно быть?

Comment: Я имела в виду, что тире не ставится перед сказуемым, выраженным прилагательным. Почему, как вы думаете? Ну и связка ЭТО в таком предложении тоже не употребляется. Сравнить: Читать - это интересно (связка возможна).

Comment: В первой же строке явная ошибка, дальше не читал: "Их два вида – глагольная связка БЫТЬ в нужной форме при именном сказуемом и специальные слова-связки, в том числе связка ЭТО.".  В учебнике приводится пример, опровергающий это: 
"Образец разбора
Жизнь – это хорошо.
Хорошо – составное именное сказуемое. Именная часть хорошо выражена наречием; грамматическая СВЯЗКА БЫТЬ – в нулевой форме; нулевая связка указывает на настоящее время изъявительного наклонения." https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html

Comment: Ваш ответ на мой вопрос достаточно хорош. Он по сути моего вопроса и даёт полезную информацию. Однако всё равно остаются непонятные вещи. Вы говорите, что есть два вида связок, из них второй вид — специальные слова-связки, в том числе связка «это». И эти два вида связок выполняют разные функции. (часть 1/4)

Comment: Но что вообще такое связка? Понятие связки, как и понятия подлежащего и сказуемого, было заимствовано из логики, причём как подлежащее и сказуемое было заимствовано в слегка изменённом виде, так и понятие связка претерпело небольшие изменения. Но суть сохранилась. В логике связка связывает подлежащее со сказуемым, потому она так и называется. Это похоже на знак равенства в математике. (часть 2/4)

Comment: В лингвистике связка считается частью сказуемого, но свою суть она сохранила. Она связывает подлежащее со сказуемым, когда сказуемое выражено не глаголом, а каким-то именем: существительным, прилагательным и т. п. В качестве связки выступают, как правило, вспомогательные глаголы бытия (быть, являться, «to be» в английском). Опущенную связку заменяют на тире. *Вася — студент.* Тут всё понятно. (часть 3/4)

Comment: Вы говорите про существование второго вида связок — специальных слов-связок, одна из которых «это». Вы пишите: *«Надо иметь в виду, что это совершенно разные связки с различными функциями, они не могут заменять друг друга»*. Какую другую функцию выполняет второй тип связок? Что с чем они связывают? Если они тоже связывают подлежащее и сказуемое, то зачем связывать два раза, как в случае: тире вместе с «это». Что значит различные функции? Различные способы связывания? Но это, как если бы я сначала обои приклеил к стене, а потом ещё гвоздями прибил. (часть 4/4)

Comment: @Eagle Я вам чуть позже отвечу на комментарии.

Comment: @user190920 Здравствуйте, «птичка неосторожная». Видите, как я к вам ласково обращаюсь.  Решили меня покритиковать – и то дело!  Где же тут у меня явная ошибка? Я говорю о том, что надо различать два похожих термина – глагольную связку «быть» в именном сказуемом и специальные слова связки (это,  значит, это значит и др.). И учебник вы мне какой-то несерьезный предлагаете – я только по академическим изданиям работаю. Да и  пример ваш нехорош, лучше уж так :  «жить – это хорошо».  И что вас здесь не устраивает? Нулевая глагольная связка пропущена, а слово-связка «это» имеется. Есть возражения?

Comment: В учебнике ясно написано: "указательная частица ЭТО стоит или может быть поставлена перед сказуемым:" и "грамматическая связка быть". Учебник авторитетный: "Материалы сайта представляют собой электронную версию книги д.ф.н., проф. Балашовой Л.В. и д.ф.н., проф. Дементьева В.В. «Курс русского языка».". Но раз вы умнее профессоров - так бы сразу и сказали. И вообще я не к вам обращался, а к Орлу. С вами не общаюсь - бестолковое дело.

Comment: К Орлу? А почему прерывает комментарии, это невежливо, еще и воспитывать вас приходится. Или знак почты надо ставить. А доктор наук, может, и правильно сказал, да очень толковые ученики всё переиначили, такое тоже бывает, я-то здесь  при чем.  И не переходите на личности - это не разрешается.  Как это вы со мной не общаетесь, когда вот сейчас мне это пишете. Еще поговорим или хватит на сегодня?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарий

В чем принципиальное различие **глагольных связок и слов-связок**? Ответ однозначный: у них разная функция, но какая именно?

1. **Глагольная связка – необходимый элемент составных сказуемых**

**Составное глагольное сказуемое:** *он решил действовать, он начал действовать.* Глагольная связка имеет фазовое или модальное значение, но ее главная функция – это выражение  **грамматических значений глагола**  (времени и наклонения), а также согласование с подлежащим в лице, числе, роде.  Без этого не обойтись, ведь инфинитив  может обозначать только основное действие.

**Составное именное сказуемое:**  *Книга – учебник жизни. Книга была для меня учебником жизни. Книга интересная. Книга оказалась интересной.*

Здесь ситуация аналогичная. В настоящем времени пропущенная связка подразумевается, а в прошедшем времени она  присутствует реально.  Связка обозначает **те же самые грамматические значения** глагола.

**Тире** на месте пропущенной связки может ставиться, а может и не ставиться (это зависит от разных факторов).

**2. Слово-связка как способ оформления предложений**

Слово-связка обязательной не является. Мы можем оформить предложении обычным образом, а можем использовать оформление **по образцу именительного темы** – такое оформление имеет более интересную грамматику.

Предложения с именительным темы строятся различным образом, но **суть одинаковая:** сначала называется предмет в качестве именительного темы, а потом приводится высказывание на эту тему. В качестве примера можно привести слова А.С. Пушкина:

*Москва! Как много в этом звуке*

*Для сердца русского слилось!*

**Как много в нем отозвалось…**

Но это художественное оформление текста, а слова-связки относятся к **грамматическому** оформлению и строится **по стандартной схеме:**

*Тверь – старинный город. Тверь – это старинный город.*  Подлежащее *Тверь* в роли именительного темы, а слово-связка ЭТО указывает на этот предмет, стоит перед сказуемым и по сути выполняет ту же роль подлежащего.

Кстати, связка может использоваться не только в И.п., например: *Начать всё заново – это  трудно. Начать всё заново – на это трудно решиться.*

И еще интересная особенность: **тире** при наличии слов-связок ставится практически всегда.

Comment: *«Глагольная связка — необходимый элемент составных сказуемых».* Это не определение, оно не раскрывает суть понятия. Это как сказать: «Колёса — необходимый элемент автомобиля». Но если человек не знал, что такое колёса, он и не поймёт. «Голова — необходимый элемент человека». И действительно, не бывает людей без головы. Но разве такое определение раскрывает, что такое «голова»?

Comment: Расшифруйте, пожалуйста, «фазовое или модальное значение». Что такое «модальность», более-менее понятно. А «фазовый» имеет слишком много значений, чтоб понять, что имеется ввиду. Модальность — это отношение. Вы это имели в виду? *«Модальность (от ср.лат. modalis — модальный, лат. modus — мера, способ) — семантическая категория, выражающая отношение говорящего к содержанию его высказывания, целевую установку речи, отношение содержания высказывания к действительности. … Понятие модальность пришло из классической формальной логики, откуда лингвистика заимствовала и другие понятия».* (Википедия)

Comment: Функцией связки не может быть выражение грамматических значений глагола. Это что-то странное. В чём цель речи? Неважно это устная или письменная речь — её цель передать информацию другим, передать свои мысли. Грамматические значения слов помогают это сделать наиболее точно. В роли связки выступает глагол, и он имеет грамматическое значение, для того чтоб сообщить, например, когда во времени имеет место данный факт. Например, кто-то сейчас студент или был им в прошлом. Но целью не может быть выражение грамматических значений, цель передать информацию, например о времени.

Comment: Функция автомобиля перевозить людей или грузы. Для этого у него есть колёса. Но функция автомобиля не в наличии колёс, а том, чтоб перевозить что-то.

Comment: *Именительный [падеж] темы... — фигура речи, на первом месте которой стоит изолированное имя существительное в именительном падеже, называющее тему последующей фразы. Его функция заключается в вызове особого интереса к предмету высказывания и усилении его звучания* (Википедия). Это фигура речи, т. е. это скорее риторический приём.

Трудно назвать *«Физика — это раздел естествознания...»* риторическим приёмом, цель которого вызвать особый интереса к предмету высказывания и усилить его звучание.

Как вы пришли к выводу, что в данном случае имеет место фигура речи — именительный [падеж] темы?

Comment: А что мне будет за то, что я  «фазовые глаголы» расшифрую, еще один минус за ответ поставите? Литературу вам надо  читать,  с терминологией знакомиться,  прежде чем философией заниматься. Ну да уж ладно, дам вам ссылку (стр. 69), там все уже расшифровано.  И фазовые глаголы, и еще много чего. https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Так и не получив ответа на свой вопрос, которой полностью бы меня устроил, я решил написать свою гипотезу:

Слово «это» изначально было указательным местоимением. С помощью него указывали на объект, который имеет в виду говорящий.

Однако указательное местоимение «это» активно использовали в случаях объяснения значения, дачи толкования объектам окружающего мира.

Например:

Ребёнок спрашивает родителя, указывая рукой на троллейбус: *«Что это?»*, а родитель отвечает: *«Это — троллейбус, он перевозит людей. Я на нём езжу на работу»*.

Из-за частого такого использования указательное местоимение «это» приобрело объяснительную коннотацию. Которая укоренилась, и слово стало прочно ассоциироваться с дачей чему-то объяснения, толкования.

Сначала «это» использовалось для указывания на материальные объекты окружающего мира и дачи им разъяснения, однако потом его использование расширилось на дачу толкований абстрактным понятиям.

Как, например: *«Физика — это раздел естествознания, наука о материи, её структуре и движении, простейших и общих законах природы»*.

Значение «это» сместилось с указательного местоимения на слово-связку с объяснительной коннотацией, которое вводит толкование, объяснение значения чего-то.

Но на самом деле в данном случае имеет место просто неправильное использование указательного местоимения «это», в качество слова, вводящего объяснение.

В предложениях типа *«Физика — это раздел естествознания…»* слово «это» выполняет функцию глагола бытия, т. е. оно то же самое, что «есть», но с оттенком дачи толкования, объяснения значения чего-то.

В русском языке в настоящем времени связку «есть» принято опускать. Однако в случае дачи определения, связка требуется для подчёркивания тождественности слова и его определения.

Поскольку использовать «есть» не принято, оно «резало» бы слух. *«Физика есть раздел естествознания...»* казалось бы неправильным.

Поэтому вместо «есть» используют «это», воспринимая его как слово-связку, вводящее  объяснение значения чего-то.

На мой взгляд, в предложениях типа «Физика — это раздел естествознания…» слово «это» — слово-связка которая выполняет функции глагола «есть», но при этом ещё сообщает, что дальше пойдёт объяснение значения, толкование.

В случаях, когда объяснения значения, толкования нет, солово «это» не используется: *«Мой брат — учитель»*. В данном случае просто утверждается, какая профессия у моего брата.

А в случае *«Учитель — это человек, который преподаёт какой-либо учебный предмет в школе»* солово «это» используется, потому что тут имеет место дача объяснения значения, толкования понятия «учитель», что это такое, кто это такой.

Зачем тире стоит вместе с «это»? «Физика — это раздел естествознания…»

Тут два варианта:

1. Тире в данном случае выполняет не функцию замены связки, а чисто интонационную функцию, показывает паузу, которая отбивает слово от его определения.
   «Физика (пауза) это раздел естествознания…»
2. Тире всё-таки выполняет функцию замены глагола-связки, а слово-связка «это» сообщает дополнительно, что дальше пойдёт именно объяснение значения, толкование.

Как итог:

«Это» в данном случае — неправильное использование указательного местоимения «это» в качестве слова-связки из-за неверного его восприятия, как дающего объяснение чему-то.

«Это» вместе с тире не нужно, но используется людьми для введения объяснительной, толковательной части предложения, для того, чтоб дать знать, что дальше идёт именно объяснение значения, толкование того, что было названо до слова «это».