# Почему подлежащее бывает несогласованным? В частности, почему глагол не согласуется с подлежащим «это»? Почему происходит обратное согласование?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика

Данный вопрос возник при обсуждении другого моего [вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464507/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC). В своём ответе пользователь user190920 написал:

> А если мы используем «это» в качестве подлежащего, тогда почему
> согласование в роде идет с именной частью, а не с подлежащим?
>
> Это была толпа. // Подлежащее - это
>
> Это был мой брат. // Подлежащее - это

И действительно, ведь должно быть «Это было толпа» и «Это было мой брат».

Почему всё-таки согласование не делается с подлежащим?

Я могу предположить, что «это» тут «универсальный солдат», как английское «it». И используется, для замены имён любых объектов. Поскольку «это» заменяет, то, что впоследствии названо толпой и братом, то и глагол согласуется по роду с тем, что было заменено словом «это»: толпой и братом. Т. е. под «это» как бы «прячется» та самая толпа и брат, и согласование происходит с тем, что «прячется» под подлежащим, а не с самим словом «это», которое как бы вообще не имеет признаков рода, а заменят всё что угодно.

Но это моё мнение, а я хотел бы узнать точный лингвистический ответ.

Ещё примеры:

*Мать посмотрела на женщину — это была Самойлова, дальше сидел её муж.* Горький, Мать.

*По всем признакам, это была личность ленивая, праздная и чувственная, которую могли занимать только сплетни, еда и супружеские ласки.* Салтыков-Щедрин М. Е., Благонамеренные речи, 1876

В предложении *«Мать посмотрела на женщину — это была Самойлова, дальше сидел её муж»* глагол «была» по логике должен согласовывается с «это», которое является подлежащим. Должно быть «это было Самойлова». Тем не менее «была» согласуется именно с «Самойлова».

Таким образом, «это» в данном случае — несогласованное подлежащие.

---

Хотелось бы понять:

1. Почему нет согласования с подлежащим в данном случае?
2. Какие ещё есть бывают несогласованные подлежащие кроме «это»?

---

Некоторую информацию на этот счёт я нашёл в Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию
Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.; §189. Согласование связки с именной частью сказуемого:

> Согласование связки не с подлежащим, а с именной частью составного
> сказуемого (так называемое обратное согласование) чаще всего
> встречается в следующих случаях:
>
> 1. при наличии в составе подлежащего имени существительного
>    собирательного с количественным значением, например: *Большая часть
>    между ними **были** довольно **добрые люди*** (Герцен)...;
>    *Большинство участников выставки **были люди** приезжие*;
> 2. при логическом подчеркивании сказуемого, например: *Последние числа
>    октября **было время** самого разгара партизанской войны** (Л.
>    Толстой). Ср. у него же: *Но погибель французов, предвиденная им одним,
>    **было** его душевное единственное **желание**; Первое помещение за дверьми **была** большая **комната** со сводами и железными решетками;
>    Так приезд Пьера **было** радостное, важное **событие**.* Следует
>    учесть, что подобные конструкции с именительным падежом в составном
>    сказуемом (так называемым именительным предикативным, или вторым
>    именительным) придают высказыванию оттенок книжности, иногда
>    архаичности;
> 3. при подлежащем, выраженном местоимением это, например: *Я случайно
>    посмотрел на эту книгу; **это была** хрестоматия...* (Гл. Успенский).

---

Тут в 1-м пункте даётся объяснение наличием в составе подлежащего имени существительного собирательного с количественным значением; во 2-м пункте логическим подчеркиванием сказуемого; в 3-м же просто констатируется как факт, без объяснения, а хотелось бы понимать причину.

Есть ещё пример несогласованного подлежащего из анализа [стихотворения](https://litlife.club/books/175528/read?page=24):

> **Московская Верона**
>
> Лежать сугроб. Сидеть заборы.
>  Вскочить в огне твое окно.
>  И
> пусть я лишь шарманщик старый,
>  Шарманкой, сердце, пой во мне.
> Полночь молчать. Хрипеть минуты.
>  Вдрызг пьяная тоска визжать.
> Ты будь мой только подвиг сотый,
>  Который мне до звезд воспеть.
> Лишь вправься в медальон окошка
>  И всё, что в сто пудов во мне,
> Что тяжело поднять букашке,
>  Так незначительно слону.
>  Ах, губы
> лишь края у раны;
>  Их кличкой бережу твоей.
>  Не мне ль
> московская Верона
>  Была обещана тобой?!
>  Зов об окно дробится
> пеной
>  И снегом упадает вниз.
>  Слеза, тянись вожжой соленой,
> Вожжой упущенной из глаз.
>  Тобой пуст медальон окошка,
>  Сугроб
> так низок до окна,
>  И муравью поднять так тяжко,
>  Что
> незначительно слону.
>  13 декабря 1922

В [статье](https://dornsife.usc.edu/alexander-zholkovsky/bib157) говорится:

> Итак, инфинитивные аграмматизмы—если угодно,
> неограмматизмы—Шершеневича немногочисленны. Основной тип:
> “инфинитивное сказуемое плюс **несогласованное подлежащее**”, но есть и
> неправильные управления; иногда налицо потенциальная синтаксическая
> двусмысленность. Два случая относятся к 1915-1916 годам, пять—к
> 1918-22.

Имеется ввиду, как я понял «Лежать сугроб. Сидеть заборы» и т. п.
Но тут скорее некий индивидуальный авторский приём.

Comment: Думаю, что просто назвали "это" исключением и все. Очевидные основания вроде на поверхности. Насчет несогласованного подлежащего - полно их: "Множество облаков плыли по небу." Но это мое мнение. Точный лингвистический ответ я бы тоже хотел узнать.

Answer (score 1):

Из диалога:

– Но это моё мнение, а я хотел бы узнать точный лингвистический ответ.

–  … я бы тоже хотел узнать.

**Ждете  лингвистов?** Знаете, у них очень мало времени: научная работа, диссертации, книги, статьи и т.д. Но не беда, вы можете узнать «точный лингвистический ответ», если **прочитаете** эти книги или статьи.

ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС

1. **Словарь Евгеньевой, почему именно он?**

Для справок: Словарь русского языка: В 4 т./ Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. – МАС. Малый академический словарь (статья на Грамоте.ру)

Подготовка к изданию началась **в 1953 г**. Организатором и руководителем работы стала **Анастасия Петровна Евгеньева (1899-1985).** В «Инструкции для составления Словаря» основные задачи словаря были определены так: «Дать нормы употребления слов, входящих в словарный состав современного русского языка (как в отношении самих слов, так и их значений)». Словарь должен был отразить появление новых слов, а также исчезновение из употребления устаревших. Он «должен удовлетворить назревшую потребность в достаточно полном и в то же время широко доступном словаре современного литературного языка».

…**В 1981-1984 гг.** вышло **второе**, исправленное и дополненное, издание словаря. Все последующие издания словаря **стереотипные.**

2. Могу предположить, что термин «несогласованное подлежащее» был предложен  давно, но, возможно, в дальнейшем  не получил  широкого распространения.
3. *Это был мой брат. Это была моя сестра.  Брат был интересным.  Сестра была интересной.*

В составном именном сказуемом используются **двунаправленные связи**.  Связка согласуется и с подлежащим,  и со сказуемым.

4. Но по словарю местоимение ЭТО имеет в таких конструкциях **средний род,** который не меняется. Поэтому  делается  только **согласование связки и именной части**. Соответственно, подлежащее ЭТО можно назвать **несогласованным подлежащим.**

Из словаря Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру:
**ЭТО.** II. это, этого; **ср.** 1. То, о чём говорится в предшествующем или последующем предложении. Экономический кризис - об этом пишут все газеты. 2. Всё то, что было перечислено в предшествующей речи. Музыка, голоса - всё это сливается в общий шум. **Пляж, море, танцы - это мне знакомо.**

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**. Увы, мое мнение также не удовлетворило автора вопроса, ответ остался **без всякого внимания** – он никак его не отметил, не принял и даже вежливого «спасибо» не сказал.

**Стоило ли стараться!** Впрочем, он ни у кого ни одного вопроса не принял, но при этом получил от общества 11 голосов...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125013/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).