# Трудный грамматический разбор

Tags: грамматика, тире, синтаксический-разбор

Дано предложение:

> *Первое, **что сделали русские**,  – **сняли** меховые шапки **и распустили** пояса на шубах. Обоим было жарко*  (Б. Акунин, 2022).

Интересует грамматический разбор нестандартного предложения.

Ясны отдельные детали:  есть **придаточное предложение**, но какое оно (определительное или местоименно-определительное)?  Просматриваются **пояснительные  отношения** между глаголами (сделали – сняли и распустили),  но они относятся к разным частям СПП.

Постановка тире представляется интонационно обоснованной, а правило какое?

А если изменить предложение:

> *Первое, что сделали русские,  **это** сняли меховые шапки и распустили пояса на шубах.*

Тогда тире уже не кажется обязательным.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

У Акунина есть подобное предложение **без тире**, но с ***ЭТО*** в неизвестной функции:

> *Первое, **что меня поразило**, это пассажиры.*

Мы его здесь уже разбирали, но так ничего и не решили.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.  Такие предложения часто встречаются даже в обычной разговорной речи,  но их грамматика  сложна для понимания.

Comment: Б. Аунин, 2022. Из неизданного?

Comment: *Тогда тире уже не кажется обязательным* — по правилам оно нужно, запятая его не отменяет.

Comment: @shampar, Да, у меня уникальный экземпляр, недавно купленный. Там указан год издания 2022. Издательство Альпина, Москва.

Comment: @oleedd  По какому правилу? Надо сначала грамматику определить, а потом правила применять.

Comment: Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. По-моему, довольно известно, что перед словом "это" необходимо тире, если схема "что-то есть что-то" в одном предложении. А там само сказуемое пропущено, но тире это не отменяет: *Первое, что сделали русские, – [это то,] что сняли меховые шапки и распустили пояса на шубах.*

Comment: Это серьезный вопрос. Внятной схемы к этому предложению современный синтаксис не предлагает. Также как и в предложении "человек это был коренастый." просто объявили "это человек" подлежащим, так и здесь можно объвить пол предложения подлежащим, а другую половину - сказуемым;) Но яснее от этого не станет.

Comment: Что-то у вас много чего пропущено.  Что сделали - что сняли...  Загадочно звучит.  И я же просила: когда работаете с предложением, ничего не вырезайте и ничего не вклеивайте.

Comment: @user190920  Может, вы предложите?  Такие предложения отнюдь не редкость. Я понимаю,что бывают фразеологические варианты, но они обычно привязаны к какому-то стандартному виду. Какова старшая конструкция, лежащая в основе? Простое предложение или СПП?

Comment: Там можно перенести: *Это/то был человек коренастый.* Здесь нет схемы "что-то есть что-то".

Comment: Ну перенесете вы, тогда называют "человек коренастый" сказуемым. Хрен редьки не слаще. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463807

Comment: Ты ведь знаешь, что сделали цари ассирийские со всеми странами ― предали их огню и мечу! [Библия. Совр. пер. Ветхий завет. Книга пророка Исайи (2011)]

Comment: @shampar Там интонационное тире вместо запятой. Прямой связи между "ты ведь знаешь" и "предали их огню и мечу" нет. Тире не обязательно, хоть и желательно.