# Каким членом предложения будет "на морских берегах"?

Tags: определения, члены-предложения, обстоятельство

Есть предложение:

> Я хочу побывать на морских берегах

Каким членом предложения будет являться `На морских берегах`?

- Единым членом предложения - обстоятельством.
- Или разными (на берегах - обстоятельством, морских - определением)?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем предложении `на берегах` - это обстоятельство, а `морских` - определение.

Проверяем:

- Задаём вопрос от `побывать`: *побывать где?* - `на берегах`. Вопрос `где?` - значит обстоятельство.
- Задаём вопрос от `на берегах`: *на берегах каких?* - `морских.` Вопрос `каких?` - значит определение.

Comment: Это тематика свободных и несвободных сочетаний,  а вы этого не учитываете. Почему вы думаете, что это свободное словосочетание?

Comment: @Sharon а почему вы думаете, что это несвободное сочетание? Это же не какой-нибудь деепричастный оборот.

Comment: А ы знакомы с темой несвободных сочетаний? Вот здесь мы обсуждали сочетание "хороший человек". Это единый член предложения и несвободное сочетание. В этой теме тоже надо определиться, найти доказательства.

Comment: @Sharon где "здесь"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474954/Он-хороший-человек-добрый-Уточнение-или-однородные-отношения    https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463807/Как-определить-именную-часть-сказуемого-со-словом-человек   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463655/Как-назвать-такое-сказуемое